# Wind service in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, quadcopter

There seems to be a few hits about wind in Gazebo, but I believe none of them go where I want it to go. This post is a last resort type of effort before going into this problem. Hopefully I'll find someone who's made progress in that regard, or at least I hope to find some people who would like this feature to be implemented and can help with the back and forth.

So a good balance between simplicity and resourcefulness, in my opinion, would be to have some sort of server keeping track of the components of wind, as well as their dynamics, and providing results of a client probing some location in space. So far nothing new, except maybe for the idea of having the superposition of a uniform flow and vortices. That would already cover gusts. Any model can then ask, "hey server, what's the wind vector at x, y and z?".

But the thing will really get interesting if a model can also inform the server of an imposed component, such as the induced flow of a propeller, modeled as a dipole, most likely, of perhaps some calculated distortion caused by a wing, or a carene, who knows... then we'd be able to have drones interfering with one another and that sort of thing.

Am I late to the party? Or should we get this going? I appreciate your input!